# containerAware and Controller in symfony2

Tags: symfony, controller, containers, extends

FOSUserBundle profile controller

```
 use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAware;
 class ProfileController extends ContainerAware
```

some functions ok ... but when i try then creat form

```
$form = $this->createForm
```

This error appear: Call to undefined method ProfileController::createForm()

BUT when i change it to this:

```
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
class ProfileController extends Controller
```

The form is rendered... so ... i dont know how can i add this controller to my class and dont remove the ContainerAware ? :/

//

MY solution ?

instead of containeraware i use

```
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareInterface;
```

And then

```
class ProfileController extends Controller implements ContainerAwareInterface
```

But i dont know i cant see a different i am noob now so... is it good solution or i will broke something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Controller is already `ContainerAware` - from Controller declaration:

```
class Controller extends ContainerAware
```

Comment: Than why this error? Call to undefined method ProfileController::createForm()

Comment: You get error with decalaration `class ProfileController extends Controller`?

Comment: no, i get your sentence wrong... you meaned when i extends controller i dont have to implement containeraware?

Comment: Yes, that exactly what I meant. It's basics of inheritance.

Answer (score 6):

To answer your original question,

Replace:

```
$form = $this->createForm
```

With:

```
$form = $this->container->get('form.factory')->create($type, $data, $options);
```

The createForm method is just a convenience method defined in Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller.  For various reasons, 3rd party libraries tend not to extend the Controller class.  Hence createForm is not available.

The real question is: why are you trying to extend the Profile controller?  In most cases it is not necessary.  It's better to do your customization by listening to events.  That of course assumes you are using the development version of FOSUserBundle.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this blog [Symfony2: Moving Away From the Base Controller](http://richardmiller.co.uk/2011/06/14/symfony2-moving-away-from-the-base-controller/) by Richard Miller

Comment: Note that link-only answers are discouraged, SO answers should be the end-point of a search for a solution (vs. yet another stopover of references, which tend to get stale over time). Please consider adding a stand-alone synopsis here, keeping the link as a reference.